# MySQL IF Statement Tally

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL that has the following fields:

- an id field
- a picture field that the filename or empty
- the same type of field for a telephone number.

I want to run an if statemtent that checks if the row has an image and telephone number

A yes to either would add one to the tally and then I need to order the results by that tally.

Is this possible?

I.e

```
ID   Pic   Phone
1           231
2    img    412 
3
```

And then the order of display would be ID 2,1,3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `pic` and `phone` columns are empty and are nulled you can do

```
select * from your_table
order by if(pic is null, 0, 1) + if(phone is null, 0, 1) desc
```

If your `pic` and `phone` columns are empty and contain empty strings you can do

```
select * from your_table
order by if(pic = '', 0, 1) + if(phone = '', 0, 1) desc
```

Comment: Sorry that is a perfect answer. I should have mentioned that pic is a text field instead of integer sorry

Comment: I simplified the problem, but in the process changed it too much

Comment: `ifnull` doesn't work that way, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull

Comment: @max: I updated the answer. Are empty fields empty strings or `null`?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY (
  IF(pic IS NOT NULL AND pic != '', 1, 0) +
  IF(phone IS NOT NULL AND phone != '', 1, 0)
) DESC
```

This takes care of both the cases where `pic` or `phone` are `NULL` or empty strings.